# How to only select the child table depending on its grandparent table's key in GORM (this key only exists in its direct Parent table)

Tags: go

[image]

I have 3 tables in this image.

A table "user" can have many "catalog_habit", and the "catalog_habit" can have many "habit".

I'm trying to find a way of using Gorm Preload to make API to display all of "habit"-relevant tables from a particular "id" primary key of "User" table.

It can display every information of 3 tables, but I want to get the "Habit" info only for Frontend guys :(

Please help me out, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you want to load and display this data.

**Just load all habits for the specified user**

```
var habits []Habit
err := db.Joins("JOIN catalog_habit ch ON ch.id = habit.catalog_id").
          Joins("JOIN user u ON u.id = ch.user_id").
          Where("u.id = ?", userID).Find(&habits).Error
```

**Load the user and its catalog habits and habits**

For this, your structs should be something like this:

```
type User struct {
  //other fields
  CatalogHabits []CatalogHabit
}

type CatalogHabit struct {
  // other fields
  UserID int64
  Habits []Habit
}

type Habit struct {
  //other fields
  CatalogHabitID int64
}
```

Then, you can write a query to load the user data, along with his catalog habits and habits:

```
var user User
err := db.Preload("CatalogHabits.Habits").First(&user, userID).Error
```

Comment: I got it done with your solution, thanks